# Blank space at the bottom of the page (dont find any solution)

Tags: html, css

I have a weird blank space at the bottom of my page. I seen all the others topics but it doesn't work...

I want ".wrapper_tabcontent:after" just at the end of the page

```
.wrapper_tabcontent:after {
  content: "";
  height: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

https://codepen.io/lopm46/pen/bGVZZpj

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTs3l.png)

[but i want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37rt3.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position it with `position: absolute;` and set `bottom: 0;` :

```
.wrapper_tabcontent:after {
    content: "";
    height: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's works :)
Position: absolute was already there but i add bottom:0 and it's works

Comment: With position:absolution the bar is on the div when i change the viewport so i replace it with position:fixed  and now its always fixed at the bottom of the page